# Display date in descending order in AngularJS datatables

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I have a list of dates coming from API and one such date is like "2017-07-05T10:53:24.000Z"

Am displaying dates in first column in datatable. In controller am defining the column like

```
$scope.dtColumnDefs = [
        DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).withOption('type', 'date'),
        DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notSortable(),
        ....
];
```

HTML

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table-header-color-yellow">
                        <th class="table-head-style">Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="review in reviews">
                        <td>{{review.date | date}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

How can i sort the dates in descending order as it is sorting in ascending order as of now?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the `order` option :

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('order', [[0, 'desc']])
```

Your usage of `columnDefs` is a little bit wrong. It should be

```
$scope.dtColumnDefs = [
  DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).withOption('type', 'date').notSortable()
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert date part into `dd/MM/yyyy`

Then in controller use

```
$scope.dtColumnDefs = [  
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef([1]).withOption('type', 'date')
];
```

and Html should be like this

```
<table class="table table-hover" datatable="ng" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs">
```